# Python PPTX workaround function for moving series to secondary axis

Tags: python-pptx

Im trying to identify a way with PPTX to move a series to the secondary axis. I know the PPTX library hasn't implemented this yet, but from what i have read its possible with LXML. Has anyone achieved this yet? Or been able to move a series to the secondary axis?

Comment: I haven't messed with secondary axis, but I did a lot of customization options that were not supported. My flow was that I would create a powerpoint file in powerpoint, then unpack the xml and copy the part that I wanted to mimic, then inject it as a string when I build powerpoint slides. It worked a good chunk of the time. Here is more information about the xml features included in python-pptx https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/xmlchemy.html